# Mongodb Update Multiple Document, Insert if not Exist

Tags: mongodb, insert-update

If upsert:true is set then mongodb insert new document if exist.
My below query working fine for single document.
Unique Index:- {fid:1,uniqueid:1,atype:1,ftype:1}

```
db.Notification.updateMany(
  {fid : 103,uniqueid:1001,atype:1,ftype:6}
  ,{ $set: { epoch: 1548484978658,actionbyuserid: 110, title: 'Good Morning To All'}}
  ,{upsert:true}
);
```

But when execute below query it is not inserting new documents for not matched documents;

```
db.Notification.updateMany(
 {fid : {$in:[101,102,103]},uniqueid:1001,atype:1,ftype:6}
  ,{ $set: { epoch: 1548484978658,actionbyuserid: 110, title: 'Good Morning To All'}}
,{upsert:true}
)
```

Is there other to check and insert not found documents ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`bulkWrite`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) operation

Array you want to update with

```
const array = [101, 102, 103]
```

Query for bulk update

```
Model.bulkWrite(
  array.map((val) => 
    ({
      updateOne: {
        filter: { _id: val, uniqueid: 1001, atype: 1, ftype: 6 },
        update: { $set: { epoch: 1548484978658, actionbyuserid: 110, title: 'Good Morning To All'} },
        upsert: true
      }
    })
  )
})
```

Comment: Thank You.This will work properly but i want to know when `const array`  have large amount of values then what will happen?

Comment: `bulkWrite`  operation can handle upto `100000` operations simultaneously.